# xaringan metropolis no ligature in code output

Tags: r, ligature, xaringan

I am using xaringan (metropolis theme) to prepare some slides for teaching R, thus I would like to see the code "as is". Xaringan currently uses ligatures in the code, which I think looks nice but is really bad when teaching the language to someone who starts from zero.

To give you an example `<-` gets rendered as

[image]

and `!=` gets rendered as

[image]

Is there any way around this?

A MWE looks like this (removing the metropolis-fonts removes the ligatures but changes the fonts of course)

````
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts]
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      highlightSpans: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```{r}
x <- 1:10
x[1] != x[2]
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the [metropolis theme](https://github.com/pat-s/xaringan-metropolis), gave the solution as using the following css, where we switch from [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) to Fira Mono.

mycss.css

```
.remark-code, .remark-inline-code {
   font-family: 'Fira Mono', 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
   font-size: 80%;
}
```

presentation.Rmd

````
---
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, mycss.css]
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      highlightSpans: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

No change in fonts here

```{r}
x <- 1:10
x[1] != x[2]
```
````